# How to access outer table in a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql

In the query below, I am trying to use the first table in a left outer join. However I am getting an error.

```
SELECT
       products.id,
       products_cstm.oem_c,
       products.mfr_part_num,
       products.description,
       products.cost,
       products.assigned_user_id,
       customfields_oo.ans
FROM products
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT  COUNT( q.id )  AS ans
                                  , pq.product_id
                           FROM   products_quotes pq 
                                     LEFT JOIN quotes q
                                           ON pq.quote_id = q.id
                           WHERE  q.deleted = 0
                           AND    pq.deleted = 0
                           AND    q.stage <> 4
                           AND  (pq.qty_shipped < pq.product_qty)
                           AND  pq.product_id = products.id
                           GROUP BY pq.product_id
                      ) AS customfields_oo
                ON customfields_oo.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN products_cstm
                ON products.id = products_cstm.id_c
WHERE  products.deleted = 0
ORDER  BY ans DESC
```

When I run the query it gives me the following error:

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause'
```

It is not allowing first "products" table in left outer join query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `customfields_oo` is a derived table not a correlated subquery. Thus, you cannot reference the outer table from within the definition of the derived table. In this case, you cannot refer to the outer `products` table from within the `customfields_oo` definition. Instead, you must do that filter in the `On` clause outside the dervied table definition.

```
Select products.id,
       products_cstm.oem_c,
       products.mfr_part_num,
       products.description,
       products.cost,
       products.assigned_user_id,
       customfields_oo.ans
FROM products
    Left Join   (
                Select pq1.product_id
                    , Count( q1.id ) As ans
                From products_quotes As pq1 
                    Left Join quotes As q1
                        On pq1.quote_id = q1.id
                Where q1.deleted = 0
                    And pq1.deleted = 0
                    And q1.stage <> 4
                    And pq1.qty_shipped < pq1.product_qty
                Group By pq1.product_id
                ) As customfields_oo
        On customfields_oo.product_id = products.id
    Left Join products_cstm
        On products.id = products_cstm.id_c
Where products.deleted = 0
Order By customfields_oo.ans Desc
```

Now, you have stated in comments that this is too slow because, say products where deleted <> 0 might be evaluated in the derived table. If that is the case, then simply expand the derived table to include the filters on the outer `products` table.

```
Select products.id,
       products_cstm.oem_c,
       products.mfr_part_num,
       products.description,
       products.cost,
       products.assigned_user_id,
       customfields_oo.ans
FROM products
    Left Join   (
                Select pq1.product_id
                    , Count( q1.id ) As ans
                From products_quotes As pq1 
                    Join products As p1
                        On p1.products.id = pq1.product_id
                    Left Join quotes As q1
                        On pq1.quote_id = q1.id
                Where q1.deleted = 0
                    And pq1.deleted = 0
                    And q1.stage <> 4
                    And pq1.qty_shipped < pq1.product_qty
                    And p1.deleted = 0
                Group By pq1.product_id
                ) As customfields_oo
        On customfields_oo.product_id = products.id
    Left Join products_cstm
        On products.id = products_cstm.id_c
Where products.deleted = 0
Order By customfields_oo.ans Desc
```

Comment: Will it evaluate the customfields_oo Query only once or for each row for the outer main select Query?

Comment: @DhavalDarji - It will evaluate the `customfields_oo` query once and then join that resultset to the outer query. Thus, the inner query executes once and the merges/joins/hashes (depending on the optimization engine) the results to the outer table (`products`).

Comment: Thanks. the Query executes fine for the above calculation, but if i want to calcuate last order date from the quote table those having current product , i have to pass current product id in customfield_oo query otherewise it is calculating wrong result (that is it calculate based on all product).

Comment: @DhavalDarji - Depending on how "last order date" is determined, why couldn't you add it to the inner query. I.e., `Max(OrderDate)` along with the count?

Comment: yes but i do not want " And q1.stage <> 4 And pq1.qty_shipped < pq1.product_qty " be part of Last Order date calculation. i want to cal. last order date from all the order that product belongs to, regardless of its (order's) stage and qty equation.

Comment: @DhavalDarji - In that case, it will likely be faster to add a second derived table similar to the one I used for the count which omits the criteria you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have `AND pq.product_id = products.id` in the where statement. Because you are `LEFT JOIN`ing on that. So I think something like this will work:

```
AND (pq.qty_shipped < pq.product_qty)
GROUP BY pq.product_id) AS customfields_oo
ON customfields_oo.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN products_cstm
   ON products.id = products_cstm.id_c
WHERE products.deleted = 0
ORDER BY openorder DESC
```

**EDIT**

You do not need to `LEFT JOIN` on the table you are `COUNT`ing on. You can also do ot like this:

```
SELECT
    .....
    (
        SELECT
           COUNT( q.id )
        FROM products_quotes pq
        LEFT JOIN quotes q
           ON pq.quote_id = q.id
        WHERE q.deleted = 0
        AND pq.deleted = 0
        AND q.stage <> 4
        AND (pq.qty_shipped < pq.product_qty)
        AND pq.product_id = products.id
    ) AS ans
 FROM products
 .....
```

Comment: if i remove " AND pq.product_id = products.id ", then the query will work but then it will count the equation for each product row and then pick 1 row that matches " ON customfields_oo.product_id = products.id " current product , but think i am doing this for 5000 product, it will count for each product row for each 5000 iteration! Thanks, for you reply i tried this but for other calculation its giving wrong result , so i have to put this condition in and alternate way.

Comment: Yes that would do the task , but i can not use this syntax as it will create other count query issue , as i am working on sugarcrm there is limitation to subquery in main listview query. :)